# Only repeat a timer a limited number of times

Tags: c#, user-interface, timer

I am trying to write an interface for a motorised stage. What I am trying to do is to create a scan feature such that the motor will move a certain distance, stop and wait a specified time and then move the same distance again. It will repeat the process until it has reached the total length specified by the user. To do this I am trying to use a Timer class features as I still want the GUI to be active during the scan.

I've got some idea of how to code it but get stuck. It would go something like:

```
private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //On click
{
    int i = 0;
    int stop = 15; //number of times I want the motor to stop

    System.Timers.Timer bTimer; //initialise timer
    bTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(waittime); //time I want the motor to wait 

    bTimer.Elapsed += PerformMove;
    bTimer.Enabled = true;

    if(i==stop){bTimer.stop()}
}

private void PerformMove(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) //event to move motor
{
     //movemotor
     i++;
}
```

Not being particularly familiar with C# or timers is undoubtedly the cause of my confusion. What's the best way to approach this problem? Any example code would be great.

If somebody could clarify what the lines

```
bTimer.Elapsed += PerformMove;
bTimer.Enabled = true;
```

actually do too that would also be of great use!

**EDIT** (sorry, didn't think this was a key part): The value of `stop` is defined upon the user click of the button from a text box within the GUI. i.e.

```
int stop = Convert.ToDouble(tbIntervalStops.Text); //grab integer from user input upon button click
```

Comment: Have you read MSDN documentation about your timer? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be the correct solution without memory leak

```
private int i = 0;
private int stop = 15; //number of times I want the motor to stop
private Timer bTimer; //initialise timer -> Thats wrong: nothing is INITIALIZED here its just defined

private void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //On click
{
    i = 0;
    stop = Convert.ToInt32(tbIntervalStops.Text); //using int because double is a floating point number like 12.34 and for counting only full numbers will be needed

    bTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(waittime); //time I want the motor to wait + Here the Timer is INITIALIZED

    bTimer.Elapsed += PerformMove; //Adds the Eventhandler, What should be called when the time is over
    bTimer.Enabled = true; //This starts the timer. It enables running like pressing the start button on a stopwatch

}

private void PerformMove(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) //event to move motor
{
    //movemotor
    i++;

    if (i == stop) //if stop would be a double here we will have the danger to get not a true because of rounding problems
    {
        bTimer.Stop();
        //now enable the Garbage Collector to remove the Timer instance 
        bTimer.Elapsed -= PerformMove; //This removes the Eventhandler
        bTimer.Dispose(); //This frees all resources held by the Timer instance.  
        bTimer = null; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing up definition and initialisation of the timer EvilFonti. Please see the edit in my question as I think this changes things a little.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could also derive from the System.Timers.Timer object and create a wrapper which has properties specific to the task. In which case, you would simply need to instantiate a MoveTimer and subscribe to it's OnPerformMoveEvent.

**Update:** Added OnMovesCompletedEvent

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TimerExample
{
    public class MoveTimer : System.Timers.Timer
    {
        public event EventHandler OnPerformMoveEvent = delegate { };

        public event EventHandler OnMovesCompletedEvent = delegate { };

        public MoveTimer()
        {
            Initialize(new TimeSpan(), 0);
        }

        public MoveTimer(TimeSpan wait, int moves)
        {
            this.Initialize(wait, moves);
        }

        private int _i;

        private int _totalmoves;
        public int Moves
        {
            get { return this._totalmoves; }
            set { this._totalmoves = value; }
        }

        private TimeSpan _wait;
        public TimeSpan Wait
        {
            get { return this._wait; }
            set { this._wait = value; }
        }

        private System.Timers.Timer _timer;

        private void Initialize(TimeSpan wait, int moves)
        {
            this._totalmoves = moves;
            this._wait = wait;
            this._timer = new System.Timers.Timer(wait.Milliseconds);
        }

        private void BindComponents()
        {
            this._timer.Elapsed += _timer_Elapsed;
        }

        private void UnBindComponents()
        {
            this._timer.Elapsed -= _timer_Elapsed;
        }

        public void StartTimer()
        {
            this._timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        public void StopTimer()
        {
            this._timer.Enabled = false;
        }

        void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            this._i++;

            if (this.OnPerformMoveEvent != null)
                this.OnPerformMoveEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);

            if (this._i == this._totalmoves)
            {
                this._timer.Stop();
                this.UnBindComponents();
                this.Dispose();

                if (this.OnMovesCompletedEvent != null)
                    this.OnMovesCompletedEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In regards to the user input where the number of moves or stops is provided as a string. I would handle this outside of the MoveTimer object.  Validation should always be performed.

First determine that the value can be parsed into an integer. If not, throw an exception to let the user know that the input was entered incorrectly.

To use the above, something like the following would be all it requires:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TimerExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Create move timer that will trigger 15 times, once every 30 seconds.
            MoveTimer moveTimer = new MoveTimer(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30), 15);

            //Substribe to the move timer events
            moveTimer.OnPerformMoveEvent += moveTimer_OnPerformMoveEvent;
            moveTimer.OnMovesCompletedEvent += moveTimer_OnMovesCompletedEvent;

            //Start the timer
            moveTimer.StartTimer();

            //What happens in between the moves performed?
        }

        static void moveTimer_OnMovesCompletedEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //All the moves have been performed, what would you like to happen? Eg. Beep or tell the user.
        }

        static void moveTimer_OnPerformMoveEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Timer has lapsed, what needs to be done when a move is requested?
        }
    }
}
```